# How to get focus ring off an NSAlert button?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbutton, nsalert

Is there any way that you can take away the focus ring of the NSAlert button. Here is what I mean:

[image: Focus ring annoyingly appears on NSAlert button]

Here is my code:

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
NSAlert *alert = [[[NSAlert alloc] init] autorelease];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Quit"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[alert setMessageText:@"Warning!"];
[alert setInformativeText:@"How do you solve this question?"];
[alert setAlertStyle:NSWarningAlertStyle];
[alert beginSheetModalForWindow:nil modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:@selector(someMethodDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo:nil];
```

Comment: Give focus to something else, like the window.

Comment: That's a pain, you can obtain all alert's button but then you have to manually set the focus ring for each one.You could just set each button focus ring to NSFocusRingTypeNone, but this doesn't work.Sincerely I gave out, waiting for someone else to answer.

Comment: For reference, if you have a destructive action and you want to take the focus off the default button, you can use this: `[[alert.buttons objectAtIndex:0] setKeyEquivalent:@""];` (default button key equivalent is `\r`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you should not do this at all, this will go against apple guidelines.

Comment: How would this go against Apple Guidelines?

Comment: If you have an alert panel, it must be a modal window with a default selection as your input.

Comment: The default selection is meant to be the default button - the one that gets clicked when you press Return. Removing the focus ring is completely fine, IMHO, since Apple does it as well in many dialogs that can lead to data loss. Apple automatically detects when you name your other button "Remove" and removes the focus ring for you. The example in my post shows how to do it manually.

Answer (score 4):

Just been trying to solve this as well and came up with this workaround:

```
NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Alert" defaultButton:@"123" alternateButton:@"" otherButton:@"" informativeTextWithFormat:@""];
NSButton *button = [[alert buttons] objectAtIndex:0];

dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [[button window] makeFirstResponder:nil];
});

[alert runModal];
```

The first two lines are straightforward - create an alert and get a button. Then the issue is to actually set the alert's panel's first responder to nil, however, it may be only *after* the alert has been run modal, so this is why the dispatch_after is used.

In your case, though, as you are using a sheet and not running it modal can use just this:

```
NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Alert" defaultButton:@"123" alternateButton:@"" otherButton:@"" informativeTextWithFormat:@""];
NSButton *button = [[alert buttons] objectAtIndex:0];

[alert beginSheetModalForWindow:window modalDelegate:nil didEndSelector:NULL contextInfo:NULL];
[[button window] makeFirstResponder:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but for the record:

To **assign the focus ring** to a specific button, use `setAccessibilityFocused = true`:

```
alert.addButton(withTitle: "Save Changes").setAccessibilityFocused = true
```

To **avoid the focus ring completely**:

Beware, `setAccessibilityFocused(false)` does not work here. Instead set `refusesFirstResponder = true` for ALL alert buttons:

```
alert.addButton(withTitle: "Save Changes").refusesFirstResponder = true
alert.addButton(withTitle: "Don't Save").refusesFirstResponder = true
```

Answer (score 0):

A quicker way would be:

```
for (NSButton* button in [alert buttons])
{
    [button setKeyEquivalent:@""];
}
NSInteger answer = [alert runModal];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this with the following one-liner. My alert has three buttons and wanted the middle button to have the keyboard focus. The left button had the keyboard focus by default, the right button is the default button.

```
[alert.buttons[1] setAccessibilityFocused:YES];
```

I also disabled the focus ring on the other buttons to be sure there wasn't a cosmetic issue.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to remove the default blue highlighting of the right NSButton from an NSAlert use this:

```
let alert: NSAlert = NSAlert()
alert.messageText = messageTitle
alert.informativeText = messageBody
alert.alertStyle = NSAlert.Style.informational
alert.addButton(withTitle: "Button 1").keyEquivalent = ""
alert.addButton(withTitle: "Button 2").keyEquivalent = ""

alert.beginSheetModal(for: self.view.window!, completionHandler: { (modalResponse: NSApplication.ModalResponse) -> Void in

    // handle response

})
```